# Check if all column values in current row is lesser than all previous rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to check if all the column values in the current row is less than the corresponding column values in all previous rows (till the current row) in a pandas dataframe (throughout entire dataframe) and create a new column with a value of 1 or 0 accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2), columns=list('AB'))

df

          A         B
0  0.417022  0.720324
1  0.000114  0.302333
2  0.146756  0.092339
3  0.186260  0.345561
4  0.396767  0.538817
5  0.419195  0.685220
6  0.204452  0.878117
7  0.027388  0.670468
8  0.417305  0.558690
9  0.140387  0.198101
```

**Option 1**
*[**`cummin`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cummin.html) with [**`shift`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)*
The concept here is to track what the minimum value is so far for each column.  If a value on a particular row is less than the prior row and all rows before it, it would have to be the new min.  We can tell if this is `True` by checking if it is less than the min so far as of the prior row.
**Note** this should work just fine with `NaN` values.

```
df.assign(New=(df < df.cummin().shift()).all(1).astype(int))

          A         B  New
0  0.417022  0.720324    0
1  0.000114  0.302333    1
2  0.146756  0.092339    0
3  0.186260  0.345561    0
4  0.396767  0.538817    0
5  0.419195  0.685220    0
6  0.204452  0.878117    0
7  0.027388  0.670468    0
8  0.417305  0.558690    0
9  0.140387  0.198101    0
```

---

**Option 2**
*`numpy` version*
*[`numpy.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html)*

```
v = df.values
c = np.minimum.accumulate(v[:-1], axis=0)
df.assign(New=np.append(False, (v[1:] < c).all(1)).astype(int))

          A         B  New
0  0.417022  0.720324    0
1  0.000114  0.302333    1
2  0.146756  0.092339    0
3  0.186260  0.345561    0
4  0.396767  0.538817    0
5  0.419195  0.685220    0
6  0.204452  0.878117    0
7  0.027388  0.670468    0
8  0.417305  0.558690    0
9  0.140387  0.198101    0
```

Comment: @MukarramPasha maybe, but I haven't thought of a way to do it.  In this problem, I care about my current row relative to every row before it.  I don't care about the prior row relative to every row before it.  So far, comparing against the cumulative minimum seems to be the best approach.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks.
*Apologies, I mistakenly deleted my first comment.

Comment: @MukarramPasha if you like or appreciate the answer, we who answer love up-votes... just sayin'

Comment: already upvoted man ;) *wondering how cool it would be if we can see which​ user upvoted*

Comment: @MukarramPasha I see that :-) you upvoted the comment.  Feel free to up vote the answer as well... but only if you find it useful.

Comment: It works fine if there is data in all cells. But what if I have Nan's in the data in the first few rows?Will this work? I want the logic to ignore Nan's. I am unable to bring that

Answer (score 0):

Using @piRsuared's DF:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2), columns=list('AB'))
Out[31]: 
          A         B
0  0.417022  0.720324
1  0.000114  0.302333
2  0.146756  0.092339
3  0.186260  0.345561
4  0.396767  0.538817
5  0.419195  0.685220
6  0.204452  0.878117
7  0.027388  0.670468
8  0.417305  0.558690
9  0.140387  0.198101
```

You can use apply to compare current row with the max of all previous rows and then convert the results to int.

```
df.apply(lambda x: (x<df[0:x.name].max()).all().astype(int),axis=1)
Out[30]: 
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    0
6    0
7    1
8    1
9    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I wanted to apply the min() logic to the command above and it works perfectly. But let us say I have a dataframe with 5 rows and five columns. If the second and the third column in the first row is Nan, for the third row, this logic is not working. (If there is Nan in previous row), for the next row the logic is not working! How do I deal with this?

Comment: Anybody knows how to make the logic work in my case. In case in my previous row, one of the columns is  Nan, it should be ignored and all other columns must be compared with the previous rows. Any help will be appreciated